# R scope: force variable substitution in function without local environment

Tags: r, scope

I'm defining functions in a loop and trying to force evaluation of a loop variable without having to carry around a private environment.

Example: a set of functions `handlers$h1`, `handlers$h2`, ..., `handlers$h6` that just pass through the 1, 2, ..., 6 to another function like so:

```
handlers <- list()
for (i in 1:6) {
    handlers[[paste0('h', i)]] <- function () {
        message(i) # <-- example
    }
}
```

So `handlers$h1()` should message 1, `handlers$h2()` should message 2, ...

Instead, all of the functions return `6`, the *current* value of `i`.

To get around this I can use a closure as [specified in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247111/evaluating-variable-within-r-loop)

```
msg <- function(i) {
    force(i)
    function () { message(i) }
}

for (i in 1:6) {
    handlers[[paste0('h', i)]] <- msg(i)
}
```

Now each function works as expected, **but** each function has to carry around its own environment:

```
handlers$h1
# function () { message(i) }
# <environment: 0x9342b80>
```

**How can I make it so that `handlers$h1` prints `function () { message(1) }`, i.e. evaluates the `i` and substitutes it directly into the definition, removing the need for the environment?**

The only ways I can think of are to:

- use `eval` (something I prefer not to do);
- write out each definition by hand with the 1-6 substituted directly (fine in this case where there are only 6 functions, but in general not scalable)

Comment: Every function in R has an associated environment: why are you worried about it?

Comment: Also, you're not getting around it by using a closure (you were doing that already), you're getting around it by using `force`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some approaches that use `body<-`

You could use `bquote`

```
handlers <- list()

for (i in 1:6) {
  handlers[[paste0('h', i)]] <- function () {}
  body( handlers[[paste0('h', i)]]) <- bquote(message(.(i)))
}

handlers$h1
## function () 
##   message(1L)
```

or `substitute`

```
for (i in 1:6) {
  handlers[[paste0('h', i)]] <- function () {}
  body( handlers[[paste0('h', i)]]) <- substitute(message(i), list(i=i))
}
```

Comment: Nice! Like thte second two. Cheers!

Comment: I wouldn't be so concerned about not using `body` -- heck, half of Mathematica is all about modifying the objects within a function :-)

Comment: @hadley -- removed `parse`. I hope not too many kittens suffered, I'll admit to it being my first thought.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately base R lacks a function for making functions by hand, but pryr supplies `make_function`:

```
library(pryr)

handlers <- list()
for (i in 1:6) {
  body <- substitute(message(i), list(i = i))
  f <- make_function(alist(), body)

  handlers[[paste0('h', i)]] <- f
}
```

Note the use of `substitute` to manually modify a quoted call.

Another cool (IMO!) function in pryr is `unenclose`, which unencloses a function by substituting in the variables defined in the enclosing environment:

```
msg <- function(i) {
    force(i)
    function () message(i)
}
msg(1)
# function () message(i)
# <environment: 0x102dc6ca0>
unenclose(msg(1))
# function () 
# message(1)
```

But their really is no downside to using the original closure.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways. They are the same except for the ## line in each:

**formals<-**

```
handlers <- list()
f <- function() message(i)
for (i in 1:6) { 
   formals(f) <- list(i = i) ##
   handlers[[paste0('h', i)]] <- f 
}
```

**trace**

```
handlers <- list()
f <- function() message(i)
for (i in 1:6) { 
   trace(f, bquote(i <- .(i)), print = FALSE) ##
   handlers[[paste0('h', i)]] <- f 
}
```