# Forcing R to evaluate variables in functions

Tags: r

Suppose you have a vector of numbers (nums) in R and you wish to make a function using each of these numbers as follows:

```
k = 1
for (i in nums){
  assign(paste("fun_",k, sep = ""), function(x) rnorm(x,i,1))
  k=k+1
}
```

When the code runs, however, all of the functions are defined as follows:

```
function(x) rnorm(x,i,1)
```

This means they will all use the current global value of i rather than the actual number given to them in the loop. Is there a was to force the function to use the numerical value rather than using the variable i in the definition of the function?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you do that? All of your functions doing exactly the same. And please don't use assign, not to mention that it did exactly what you told it to do. So not sure what are you so surprised about

Comment: Hi David, I don't think I explained it correctly. Suppose nums is c(1,2,3,4,5), I want to create 5 functions as follows:
fun_1 = function(x) rnorm(x,1,1),
fun_2 = function(x) rnorm(x,2,1),
fun_3 = function(x) rnorm(x,3,1)
etc.
Also what is the issue with assign?

Comment: Again, why would you do that? Just create one function called fun that will accepts nums as a parameter, such as f`un <- function(x, nums) rnorm(x, nums, 1)`. The whole idea of creating a function is to make it generic, otherwise just use `rnorm` directly. Regarding `assign`- look it up.

Comment: Solved, thanks for not helping
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627701/r-scope-force-variable-substitution-in-function-without-local-environment?rq=1

Comment: Suggesting alternative way *is* helping (as I see it). I still think you are doing a wrong thing here and you shouldn't either create multiple functions or use `assign`. What you are doing is called "XY problem"

Comment: Perhaps this scenario is useful when creating decorators/ [function operators](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/function-operators.html#function-operators)?