# Calling functions from a list recursively

Tags: r

I am writing a program in which I need a function to call a function that was determined in the period beforehand, which may again call the function that was determined before itself and so on. However, I am finding myself inable to implement this in R.

Here is a minimal example of what I am trying to do:

```
functions <- list()
functions[[1]] <- function(x){
  x
}

for (i in 2:10)
{
  functions[[i]] <- function(x){
    functions[[i-1]](x) + x
  }
}
```

So after running this script, what I would want to happen is that when I call `functions[[10]](1)` is that R determines the value the function would have had in period 9, for which it needs the value of the function in period 8 and so on and adds the input to it. (So obviously, the output should be 10).

The problem is that when I do this, the function calls itself infinitely. The list looks like this:

```
[[1]]
function (x) 
{
    x
}

[[2]]
function (x) 
{
    functions[[i - 1]](x) + x
}

[[3]]
function (x) 
{
    functions[[i - 1]](x) + x
}

(...)
```

So when I call `functions[[10]](x)`, it evaluates to `functions[[9]](x) + x`, but `functions[[9]]` then keeps calling itself over and over again.

Is there anything I can do so that I force R to write the value of `i - 1` into each element of the list, such that it would look as follows?

```
[[1]]
function (x) 
{
    x
}

[[2]]
function (x) 
{
    functions[[1]](x) + x
}

[[3]]
function (x) 
{
    functions[[2]](x) + x
}

(...)
```

Or is there any other way I could do what I am trying to do here?

(Obviously, in the above given example, I could just sum, but in the application I am trying to simulate here, this is not possible and I can't think of another way to do it other than having each function call the one before it).

Comment: Look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247111/evaluating-variable-within-r-loop) maybe, following the accepted solution you could try `functions[[i]] <- eval(parse(text=paste0("function(x){functions[[",i-1,"]](x) + x}")))`

Comment: Look at the ``formals( f )`` function. I'll make an example showing what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
functions <- list()
functions[[1]] <- function(x){
    x
}

for (i in 2:10)
{
    functions[[i]] <- function(x,i){
        functions[[i-1]](x) + x
    }
    formals(functions[[i]])$i <- i
}
functions[[10]](5) 
# 50
```